# Super Key is disabled on 17.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, activities-overview

I upgraded my Lenovo laptop from 17.04 to 17.10. After upgrading my Super Key is no longer working. It can't be set from keyboard shortcut.

I used to open Activities with Super Key on 17.04 Gnome.

How can I enable Super key (Windows Key) again?

Comment: All the shortcuts combined with Super Key is no longer working.

Answer (score 1):

You may press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  to open *Activities* as an alternative. ([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html))

Comment: Alt + F1 also not working . Alt + Fn + F1 open Application Menu instead of Activities. My Super Key is disable . I need to enable again . But I can't find how to enable Super Key in Gnome :)